# Python range of a list?

Tags: python, list

I'd like to be able to get a range fields of a list.

Consider this:

```
list = ['this', 'that', 'more']

print(list[0-1])
```

where the `[0-1]` should return the first *and* second fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use Python's [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) for this:

```
>>> lst = ['this', 'that', 'more']
>>> print(lst[:2])
['this', 'that']
>>>
```

The format for slice notation is `[start:stop:step]`.

Also, I changed the name of the list to `lst`.  It is considered a bad practice to name a variable `list` since doing so overshadows the built-in.

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
list = ['this', 'that', 'more']
print(list[0:2])
```